# Branching from an existing private repo for a new Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github

How can I create

I created a new rails app with the command rails new. There is a private repo in Github XYZ which I have access to. I forked the private repo XYZ, now how do I connect the new rails app with this private repo and create a new branch where I can work on?

Answer (score 0):

Typically if you are wanting to work on a repo branch then you would fork the repo and pull down a copy.  From there you would branch and do your work.

If however you do want a separate branch with a new rails app you can set the remote

```
git remote add origin git@github_repo:repo_fork
```

then you can push your branch to your fork like:

```
git push origin branch_name
```